Characterizing the complex structure on a non-compact Riemann surface
A consequence of Torelli's theorem is that a closed Riemann surface $X$ is determined by its period matrix. More precisely, fix $(\alpha_i)$ a basis of $H_1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ and for $J$ some complex structure on $X$ consider the space of $J$-holomorphic 1-forms $H_J^0(X, \mathbb{C})$ of basis $(\zeta_j)$. Then $J$ is determined by the $\int_{\alpha_i} \zeta_j$.
Does there exist a generalization of this to non-compact Riemann surfaces ? As there would not be a Jacobian, I expect that the theorem does not generalizes directly. However, does there exist some way to characterize the complex structure on $X$ using only these kinds of holomorphic and topological information on $X$ ?

There is a survey on this topic: R. Accola, Some classical theorems on open Rismann durfaces, Bull AMS 73 (1967) 13-26. It is quite old, of course, but I don't think that significant progress has been made since then.
